# Setting the "height" on child elements based on an absolutely-positioned parent

Tags: css

I have a parent element, and I want to set the height of an element within the parent. For example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <p id="child"></p>
</div>
```

Now we know that in order the set a height for the "child", we must have some value of height set on "parent" also. Otherwise there will be no effect of setting any height value on the "child" alone.

```css
#parent { height: 200px; }
#child { height: 75%; }
```

This will set the height for the "child" to be 75% of 200px. If we remove the height on "parent", "child" won't have any height set.

Now, what I found out was that instead of setting a height, if we set the positioning of the "parent" to be absolute, we can get away without setting any height, and the height value on the "child" would still work:

```css
#parent { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; }
#child { height: 75%; }
```

What I want to know is whether this is a standard behavior or something that just works by chance. Also, if it is standard, does this mean that giving an element a layout (by setting it's position) gives it some value for height implicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is this: for an absolutely-positioned element, if you set the offsets on opposite sides (e.g. `left` and `right`, or `top` and `bottom`) to zero, then the element will stretch to the width or height of its containing block respectively.

Not only is this a commonly-used trick, but it is also a standard behavior. The gory details are [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height) in the spec; the key lies in this equation:

> For absolutely positioned elements, the used values of the vertical dimensions must satisfy this constraint:
>
> > 'top' + 'margin-top' + 'border-top-width' + 'padding-top' + 'height' + 'padding-bottom' + 'border-bottom-width' + 'margin-bottom' + 'bottom' = height of containing block

(This is for calculating heights; there's a corresponding equation for calculating widths as well, which can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width).)

So, assuming defaults for all other values, this means

> 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 'height' + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 = height of containing block

The containing block of an absolutely-positioned element whose ancestors are all static is always the viewport (or the *initial containing block*), which is typically of the same height as a browser's viewing area (or the Results iframe in jsFiddle for example). This creates the effect I've just described.

Because you did not specify an explicit height for your parent element, this gives it an implicit height for calculating the height of your child element [as a percentage](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block).

In fact, even if you set `top` and/or `bottom` to some non-zero value, the boxes will scale according to the above equation.

Note also that the "height of the generated box's containing block" does not refer to the specified or computed value of `height` for that block, but the used value, i.e. the height as it is calculated rendered on screen. This may have been the source of your confusion on why you can get away without setting `height` on the parent element, yet the browser still knows how to calculate the height of the child element based on some implicit height.

Comment: Thanks for digging into the spec.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Yes. This is a standard behavior.

Always when you set the `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` for an `absolute` element, it means set the `height` to the parent `height` value. For example, consider an `relative` element with `height: 400px;`, if you have a `absolute` child element with `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;`, the child element also will be `height: 400px;`

```
<div style='position: relative;height: 400px'>
    <div style='position: absolute;bottom: 0;top:0;'>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's correct. But in my case, the "parent" element is `body` whose parent is `html` which does not have any height set on it.

Comment: So, you should first set the `height` of `html` and `body` to 100%. You will get the expected result.