# percentage values for absolute elements refers to browser width and height?

Tags: html, css

As far as I know, when using css percentage for properties value for an relative element, this element checks the value of its parent and adjust the size based on this parent size.

What is the scenario for absolute elements?
I was looking through a css file and I found this:

```
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Is this ok to have percentage on absolute elements to get its browser width and height?

Comment: Afaik % widh still refers to their parents even if it's position: absolute;. Could be wrong, that's why it's a comment.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: That's what the spec seems to say ([`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) and [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-height-property)) but I could be reading it wrong. See the counter-example below.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: [Fail.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082392/setting-the-height-on-child-elements-based-on-an-absolutely-positioned-parent/13082915#13082915) I've seen this spec many times and somehow I interpreted it wrongly this time. The containing block for an absolutely-positioned element is usually the viewport (barring exceptions that don't apply here), and that's what the spec is referring to. Maybe I'm just tired.

Comment: Hmm. That's interesting, I was sure. But thanks for clearing it up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an element has `position:absolute`, the `width` and `height` percentages are calculated based on the whole browser dimensions.

See below code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #a {
                position: absolute;
                width:50%;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body onload="alert(document.getElementById('a').offsetWidth);">
        <div style="width:200px;">
            <div id="a">Hello</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Even though the width of parent div is only `200px`, the element displays half of the browser width.

Once I change it to `position:relative;`, the alert will say `100`.