# :before as wide as element

Tags: html, css

I've tried applying `width`but it did not help, what I want is to make clickable, outter padding.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px;
}

.btn:before {
  content: '';
  min-height: 60px; /*dont mind*/
  width: 100px;
  /*issue*/
  margin: -10px -10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">btn</a>
```

How can I match inner width with the :before width if pxs are manual and % can not be used (absolute positioning)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [percentage values for absolute elements refers to browser width and height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276317/percentage-values-for-absolute-elements-refers-to-browser-width-and-height)

Comment: possible not, not even the same issue

Comment: Uhm... it seems to be pretty much the same issue, and the accepted answer seems to be the solution to your problem as well. Are you aware that `::before` and `::after` are children of the element you add them to?

Comment: @Siguza as you can see, that was not an issue :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: relative` and suddenly you can use percent values.

```css
.btn {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:before {
  content: '';
  min-height: 60px; /*dont mind*/
  width: 100%;
  /*issue*/
  margin: -10px -10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">btn</a>
```